# Unable to initialize UICollectionView in Xcode Playgrounds

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, swift-playground

I tried to initialize a UICollectionView:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
```

But all I'm getting is

```
error: Execution is interrupted, reason: signal SIGBART
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To initialize a UICollectionView use `init(frame: CGRect, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout)`, check [Apple Doc:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview)

```
let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100), collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
```

Comment: That was simple, how could I missed that! Thanks dude

Comment: Without including the collectionViewLayout, this crashed playgrounds so hard for me it showed the homescreen of the simulator running the live view!